# c# - create table if not exists in sqlite feedback/return

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

in my program I want to create a table in a database if it doesn't already exist and fill it with data. 
Now the obvious solution is of course:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'tablename' ("some columns and values");
```

However, within my program I need a feedback, if the table did already exist or not. 
I came up with a solution using

```
SELECT 1 FROM 'tablename' LIMIT 1;
```

throwing/catching an exception if the table doesn't exists, but since that is the intended case it seems counterintuitive to me to throw execptions during normal program runs.

So, the question I want to ask, if there is some return value within the command object, that I can use after the "Create if not exists.." query to verify if a new table was created or not.